# jQuery error - $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code:

```
$('body').mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(hide)
    var hide = setTimeout(function() {
        hidePlayer()
    }, 2000)
    showPlayer()
})
```

works fine if I link to a remote jquery library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or if I link to my local file twice:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but using only one jquery script tag:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I've tried different versions of jquery, using window.onload, replacing $ with jQuery, tried type="text/javascript" and charset="UTF-8"... I'm stumped.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is your $(document).ready ?

Comment: Probably one of your scripts is forcing jQuery to use its [`no conflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode.

Comment: there's something else going on, including jquery twice back to back should be no different than including it once other than messing with any subsequent (and likely incorrect) use of noConflict.

Comment: @Eric What difference does that make? If `$` isn't defined, `$(document)` won'twork.

Comment: When you link to the jQuery file twice are you absolutely sure you're linking to the *same* file twice? I can't - with what little there is at the moment - believe that you might need to link to the same file twice for jQuery to work and be loaded.

Comment: If the undefined `$` problem is solved you will face another problem. The "player" will always be hidden after 2 seconds because `hide` will always be `undefined` when you call `clearTimeout(hide)`

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Eric, $(document).ready just gives me the same "$ is not defined" error.  I tried running my script inside a window.onload but it didn't change anything.

Comment: BSMP, obviously i want jquery to work the way its supposed to, with one script tag.

Comment: David, yes, I'm literally cut and pasting the line twice.  For some reason it works that way.

Comment: For what it's worth, the problem was with *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*. Your question doesn't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure how its set up but have you run your code after the inclusion of the js file so something like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
          $('body').mousemove(function() {
              clearTimeout(hide)
              var hide = setTimeout(function() {
                  hidePlayer()
              }, 2000)
              showPlayer()
          })
      })();
    </script>
```

Try this vanilla js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
          document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){
                showPlayer();
                var hide = setTimeout(hidePlayer, 2000);
          })


          function hidePlayer(){
                clearTimeout(hide);
              .......
          }

      })();
    </script>
```

Comment: That's not it Bro.  The jquery link is in my head and my script is in the body.

Comment: have a look in your browser console for any load errors, as it coud lbe it cannot find the file in its location etc so in say chrome open it the developer comsole.

Comment: also updated code to a more better way to do what you want... within out jquery, might help or not?  But do have a look at the JS Console for any issue, and post them here for more of and issue.

Comment: Great idea!  I prefer doing it the vanilla way.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably including jquery *after* your script.

Comment: That's not it.  The jQuery link is in my <head> .  My script is in the <body>.